# Spinning circles css3 transition

Tags: html, css, transition, geometry

I want to make 3 spinning circles but I can`t find any examples.

How I need it to work:
There are 3 circles (big,medium,small)
I want to rotate them on hover (small and medium change position on big circuit)

**IMG:**

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64675374/circle/circle1.png
```

**Single img:**

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64675374/circle/small.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64675374/circle/medium.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64675374/circle/big.png
```

Here is for code for one circle. But how make a big circle a background of it and add medium circle

http://jsfiddle.net/AqKYC/293/

**CSS:**

```
.dot{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
     background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64675374/circle/small.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
.sun{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-name:orbit;
    -webkit-animation-duration:5s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -moz-animation-name:orbit;
    -moz-animation-duration:5s;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes orbit { 
from { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) } 
to { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg) } 
}
@-moz-keyframes orbit { 
from { -moz-transform:rotate(0deg) } 
to { -moz-transform:rotate(360deg) } 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="sun">
 <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach to the problem:

[Example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/EPy52/)

First I placed the elements like this:

[image: Image positions]

The trick is to add the css attribute `translateX(260px)` that is *(half of the biggest image `circle/big.png`)*, and then you just need to animate the rotation!

```
from { -transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(260px) }
to   { -transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(260px) }
```

---

Fullcode:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="loading">
    <div class="circle-small"></div>
    <div class="circle-medium"></div>
    <div class="circle-big"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:** *(shortned - webkit only, full code at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/EPy52/))*

```
.loading {
    width: 688px;
    height: 688px;
    position: relative;
}
.loading > div {
    position: absolute;
}
.circle-small {
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64675374/circle/small.png');
    width: 162px;
    height: 161px;
    margin-left: 348px;
    margin-top: 348px;
    -webkit-animation: myOrbit1 3s linear infinite;
}
.circle-medium {
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64675374/circle/medium.png');
    width: 338px;
    height: 339px;
    margin-left: 260px;
    margin-top: 260px;
    -webkit-animation: myOrbit2 4s linear infinite;
}
.circle-big {
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64675374/circle/big.png');
    width: 518px;
    height: 517px;
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-top: 170px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myOrbit1 {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(260px) rotate(0deg); }
    to   { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(260px) rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes myOrbit2 {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(260px) rotate(0deg); }
    to   { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(260px) rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

Comment: By the way, this is CSS3 only, no JS.

Comment: excellent! This is great. Thants a lot. Now I only must rewrite it on hover.;)