# How to make a circle spinning within another circle using Webkit Animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation, webkit

I'm trying to make a circle spinning within another spinning circle.

I'm using Webkit Animation. The code works for two separate circles, but not connected.

```
<style> 
.loader { 
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db; 
  margin-left: 170px; 
  width: 120px; 
  height: 120px; 
  -webkit-animation: spin .25s linear infinite; /* Safari */ 
  animation: spin .25s linear infinite; 
} 
.loader2 { 
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db; 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 300px; 
  -webkit-animation: spin2 .25s linear infinite; /* Safari */ 
  animation: spin2 .25s linear infinite; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); } 
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } 
} 

@keyframes spin { 
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); } 
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); } 
} 
@-webkit-keyframes spin2 { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); } 
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}   
@keyframes spin2 { 
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); } 
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); } 
} 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h2>How To Create A Loader</h2> 

<div class="loader">
    </div> 
 <div class="loader2"></div> 
</body></html>
```

Expected output is one circle spinning inside another spinning circle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spinning circles css3 transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056266/spinning-circles-css3-transition)

Comment: it works when you put one tag inside another, if that's what you intend to do: https://jsfiddle.net/tcdmuj18/

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positions of divs. Something like this:

```
.loader {
    position: absolute;
    (rest of code and delete margin)
}

.loader2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: -70px; top: 100px;
    (rest of code)

}
```